# Excel how to display text based on values of two cells

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a way to display the word "Lumpsum" or "Days" based on Hiring Date.C74 & D74 which gets subtracted into number of days + 1 and gets displayed on the cell H71. If H71 is any number G71 should show as "Days" and if there is an error or the value displays as "-" then it should show as "Lumpsum"

Cells Values are as follows :

1- G71 -

```
=IF(HD72="-","LUMPSUM",IF(D72="Mob & Demob of 6"" Dewatering Pump","LUMPSUM",IF(D72="Well point","LUMPSUM","DAYS")))
```

2- H71 -

```
=IFERROR(IF(D72="Mob & Demob of 6"" Dewatering Pump", F74,D74-C74+1),"-")
```

3- D72 is a drop down list with these values :

a) Dewatering Pump - G71 should be "Days"

b) 6" Dewatering Pump - G71 should be "Lumpsum"

c) Mob & Demob of 6" Dewatering Pump - G71 should be "Lumpsum"

d) Standby Pump - G71 should be "Days"

e) Well point - G71 should be "Lumpsum"

f) Well Points Buried at site - G71 should be "NOS"

[image]

Comment: You can check if a value is a number with `ISNUMBER()` and an Error with `IFERROR()` so `=IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(H71),"Days","Lumpsum"),"Lumpsum")` ?

Comment: Thank you Very much, your solution was nice and simple.

Comment: I have one more item on my drop down list, that if selected G71 should show as "Nos" even though numbers should show as "Days" but particularly for that selection it should show as "Nos". How do i come about adding an extra validation ? Thank you

Comment: Selecting Dewatering Pumps should show as days as its calculated by the difference in two date values